# How to read csv file with full path in panda

Tags: python, atom-editor

I have got this code in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

path_1 = Path('C:/Users/wotesi/Documents/Cloud/Documents/Python/Programmas/panda/')
print(path_1)
full_path = path_1.joinpath('failu_nosaukumi.csv')
print(full_path)
```

and I got actual result (full path to file and name of the file), but when I try to read that file like:

```
faili = pd.read_csv(full_path, header=None, index_col=0).reset_index()
```

I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wotesi\AppData\Local\Temp\atom_script_tempfiles\d35090b0-aa8b-11ea-bb80-793ba6a5bb7c", line 19, in <module>
    faili = pd.read_csv(full_path, header=None, index_col=0).reset_index()
  File "C:\Users\wotesi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\wotesi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 448, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\wotesi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 880, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\wotesi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1114, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\wotesi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1891, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 374, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 674, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File C:\Users\wotesi\Documents\Cloud\Documents\Python\Programmas\panda\failu_nosaukumi.csv does not exist: 'C:\\Users\\wotesi\\Documents\\Cloud\\Documents\\Python\\Programmas\\panda\\failu_nosaukumi.csv'
```

Moreover - when I run the same code (without full path, just all files are in the same directory) with Anaconda/Spyder, I got no errors. This error is generated in Atom. How to modify code to make it running also in Atom? Besides when I compile that code to exe module and try to run from other Windows machine, it also gives the same error message - no files are found. Any solution will work for me. Thanks!

Comment: I just changed code to this `path_1 = Path('C:\\Users\\wotesi\\Documents\\Cloud\\Documents\\Python\\Programmas\\panda\\')`, but I got the same error message `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File C:\Users\wotesi\Documents\Cloud\Documents\Python\Programmas\panda\failu_nosaukumi.csv does not exist: 'C:\\Users\\wotesi\\Documents\\Cloud\\Documents\\Python\\Programmas\\panda\\failu_nosaukumi.csv'`

Comment: What is the ouput of os.isdir(you_path) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
path_1 = Path(r'C:\Users\wotesi\Documents\Cloud\Documents\Python\Programmas\panda')
faili = pd.read_csv(path_1.joinpath('failu_nosaukumi.csv'), header=None, index_col=0).reset_index()
```